# Cannot recover from RejectedExecutionException for some reason

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

So, I am trying to write a task that just keeps running until you tell it to stop:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

def runUntilShutdown(f: => Unit) = {
  val ctx = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(null)
  import ExecutionContext.global
  def runTask(): Future[Unit] = Future(f)(ctx)
    .flatMap(_ => runTask())(ctx)
  runTask()
    .recover { case _: RejectedExecutionException => () }(global)
    .onComplete { _ => println("Done") }(global)
  ctx
}

val ctx = runUntilShutdown(Thread.sleep(1000))
ctx.shutdown
```

I want this to just print "Done" at the end, but that never happens.

Instead, a stack trace for `RejectedExecutionException` is dumped to  stderr:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.fullExternalPush(ForkJoinPool.java:1870)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.externalPush(ForkJoinPool.java:1834)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.execute(ForkJoinPool.java:2973)
at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:157)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been fixed for Scala 2.13* with the new implementation of Future & Promise,
you can try your example out on Scala 2.13.0-M5, but you're going to have to call `shutdownNow` on your EC otherwise it will just keep going since it will not be accepting new tasks but it is already running your Future.

Example output:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.13.0-20181205-121558-76b34c4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

scala> import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

scala> def runUntilShutdown(f: => Unit) = {
     |   val ctx = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(null)
     |   import ExecutionContext.global
     |   def runTask(): Future[Unit] = Future(f)(ctx)
     |     .flatMap(_ => runTask())(ctx)
     |   runTask()
     |     .recover { case _: RejectedExecutionException => () }(global)
     |     .onComplete { _ => println("Done") }(global)
     |   ctx
     | }
runUntilShutdown: (f: => Unit)scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutorService

scala> val ctx = runUntilShutdown(Thread.sleep(1000))
ctx: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutorService = scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3@23d060c2[Running, parallelism = 8, size = 1, active = 1, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]

scala> ctx.shutdownNow
res2: java.util.List[Runnable] = []

scala> Done
```

*: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9071 (It was not possible to implement the correct behavior with the old implementation of Future & Promise, hence no backport to 2.12 currently planned.)

Comment: Ah, nice ... I thought I was loosing my mind :)
Re. `showdownNow`: `flatMap` _is_ a new task, isn't it? (otherwise, does it eve need the context?). I wanted let the current task finish, and have the `flatMap` fail to start next one ... But it's quite some time before I have anything with 2.13, so, it's all rather academic at this point. Back to the ugliness of `var stopped = false` for me :(

Comment: It's not necessarily a new task in the sense of a newly created Runnable submitted to the `execute` method—which is why you need to do the `shutdownNow` in order to shut everything down at once.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have a recursion `def runTask(): Future[Unit] = Future(f)(ctx).flatMap(_ => runTask())(ctx)` that will never end. Thus no output for `Done` ever printed because the future is never completed.

This example handles the exception correctly

```
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
  import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
  import java.util.concurrent.Executors

  def runUntilShutdown(f: () => Unit) = {
    implicit val ctx = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
    Future { f() }
      .recover { case _: RejectedExecutionException => () }
      .onComplete { _ =>
        println("Done")
      }
    ctx
  }

  val ctx = runUntilShutdown { () =>
    Thread.sleep(10000)
  }
  ctx.shutdown()
```

Comment: And what part of it is supposed to do the looping?

Comment: @ Andrey Tyukin The question is about recovery and not looping. Recovery is not possible if task never finishes because of recursion. It runs again and again without reaching code in `.recover`. Thus the exception is printed when context is shutdown.

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc  Technically, it's not really recursion (there is no stack involved). It just keeps resubmitting the job to the executor. You are wrong that it "never finishes" - the chain will terminate when then executor is shut down, and that's when I expect it to `recover`, and print out the message (this last part is not working - thus my question). Yes, this  question _is_ "about looping". Your implementation does something different.  BTW, it DOES NOT print out "Done" in the end either (_but_, there is no stack trace dumped to stderr either - mystery thickens :) ).

Comment: Ah, I know, you just missed parenthesis after `f` (I edited your answer to fix that) - that's 'why there was no exception - it, was just completing right away. Now, the behavior is the same as in my case - stack traceback on stderr, and no "Done" message at the end. This is still a DIFFERENT case from what I was talking about though: note how there are TWO execution contexts in my question? That's important. Yours just fails because you are trying to use the same `ctx` with `.recover` after it is already closed.